# How to send password while using ssh command in os.system?

Tags: python, ssh

For example, I have the code below:

```
cmd = "ssh <host>"
os.system(cmd)
```

How I can send the password in the python script so that I don't have to type the password every time?

Comment: Were you wanting to implement using an agent? Check out http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent. After the image of agent Smith it gives a good example of running an ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Use [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko), like so:

```
sh = paramiko.SSHClient()
sh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
```

There are also many good demos in the paramiko github repo.